# Get all entries for a structure section including disabled

Tags: plugin-development, templating, status

I am building a plugin and in that plugin I am trying to grab all entries including disabled ones.  My structure is a single entry as the parent and then it will have multiple levels of children.  Currently I am grabbing the main parent with this code.

```
{%   set events = craft.entries.section('events').first() %}
```

Then I am doing nested for loops to work my way down such as the following.

```
{% for event in events.children() %}
   {% for day in event.children %}
      {% for session in day.children() %}
      {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works just fine but the issue is it will not return the disabled entries.  I have noticed the status(null) when you are doing a find but I have not figured out a way to do it with the for loops.  I intend to keep the relationship structure in the ui so I am not looking to just get a random ordered list of all entries.

Any help would be appreciated and I am open if there is a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% set events = craft.entries.section('events').first() %} 
{% for event in events.children().status(null).find() %}
   {% for day in event.children().status(null).find() %}
      {% for session in day.children().status(null).find() %}
      {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`event.children()` does not return an array of elements but an object of type `ElementCriteriaModel` the same as `craft.entries` thus you can append whatever you want until you execute it with `find()` or `first()`